# restrict amount of pull requests Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Current problem: There are way too much pull requests in our team. And the hope is, that if it's not possible to create new pull requests the people starting reviewing more often.

So my question: is there any way to restrict the amount of pull requests on bitbucket?

For example only 20 pull requests are valid and if someone wants to create the 21 its not possible.

Thanks
Severin

Comment: I added an update to the question with a possible third party solution, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not a feature. This isn't a use case I've heard before; typically I've seen teams small and large simply use as many PR's as are needed for the items of work in flight. If it were me I'd view this as more of a symptom than the root problem; there should be tickets in your bug/feature tracking system (whether you're using Bitbucket's built in issue tracker, something more comprehensive like Jira or similar, etc.) that define the open work items to be completed. That would be a good place to limit new issues being picked up until old ones are closed. Even then, it sounds like there's a bigger problem to solve with the expectations within your team, and trying to solve this by leveraging tooling to create artificial guard rails may simply be avoiding the larger issue of how the team works together.

I realise that's not really an answer to the technical aspect of this question, but short of writing a lot of custom code/integrations (which might be more doable on Bitbucket Server, since you can write your own plugins and intercept low-level server-side events to achieve this sort of thing) I'm not aware of any solutions in Bitbucket, or in other git hosting products, that would achieve this.

Full disclosure: I work for Atlassian

UPDATE: I discovered this open source project: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate - it looks like it can implement a solution like the one you're describing: https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#prconcurrentlimit. Worth checking out!